# xdotool how to multiple mouse clicks

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, xdotool

i've tried to do a multime mouse moves with shift and click but only the first click happens and i think shift wont

````
xdotool search --class appname \
keydown shift
        mousemove --window %1 875 506 \
       click 3
mousemove --window %1 808 512 
click 3
mousemove --window %1 805 446 
click 3
mousemove --window %1 809 380 
click 3
 mousemove --window %1 873 379 
click 3
mousemove --window %1 935 381 
click 3
mousemove --window %1 934 446 
click 3
mousemove --window %1 937 509 
click 3
keyup shift```
````